# Could you explain this question? i am new to ML, and i faced this problem, but its solution is not clear to me

Tags: machine-learning

The problem is in the picture

Question's image:
[image]

Question 2
Many substances that can burn (such as gasoline and alcohol) have a chemical structure based on carbon atoms; for this reason they are called hydrocarbons. A chemist wants to understand how the number of carbon atoms in a molecule affects how much energy is released when that molecule combusts (meaning that it is burned). The chemists obtains the dataset below. In the column on the right, kj/mole is the unit measuring the amount of energy released. examples.

You would like to use linear regression `(h a(x)=a0+a1 x)` to estimate the amount of energy released `(y)` as a function of the number of carbon atoms `(x)`. Which of the following do you think will be the values you obtain for `a0` and `a1`? You should be able to select the right answer without actually implementing linear regression.

```
A) a0=−1780.0, a1=−530.9  B) a0=−569.6, a1=−530.9
C) a0=−1780.0, a1=530.9   D) a0=−569.6, a1=530.9
```

Comment: Which part is not clear exactly?

Comment: Where and how to know the values of a0 and a1?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all a0s are negative but two a1s are positive lets figure out the latter first.
As you can see by increasing the number of carbon atoms the energy is become more and more negative, so the relation cannot be positively correlated which rules out options c and d.

Then for the intercept the value that produces the least error is the correct one. For the 1 and 10 (easier to calculate) the outputs are about -2300 and -7000 for a, -1100 and -5900 for b, so one would prefer b over a.

PS: You might be thinking there should be obvious values for a0 and a1 from the data, it's not. The intention of the question is to give you a general understanding of the best fit. Also this way of solving is kinda machine learning as well

Comment: Thank you, man! Now, it is a little bit clear, but for the value of a0 (in your answer's second paragraph) i am still confused, could you tell how you measured least error and how did you make decision to prefer b over a  for those numbers(-2300, -7000 and -1100 , -5900)?

Comment: replace a0 and a1 in the linear equation with x=1 and 10. The one that gives closest value to the table is the best. You don't really need a calculator for it, just a rough summation is enough.